# Is the Linear Motion Battle System (used in the Tales series by Namco Bandai) patented?

Tags: patent-infringement

How would I find the a patent? I'm curious, because I plan on developing an RPG in the vein of that sort of battle system.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1. The question is whether the "linear motion battle system" you intend to build infringes any issued US Patents.  These could be owned by Namco Bandai or other companies.
2. Because modern technology is complex, determining infringement is complex. If you are concerned that patents may have been issued on the linear motion battle system which you intend to build, you should have a prior art search done by a [patent agent (or a patent attorney)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_attorney#United_States) before building it. The goal would be to determine whether you need to invent around any specific patents.
3. A number of [active contributors to Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) are patent agents or patent attorneys who do prior art searches on a regular basis.  You should feel free to reach out any of them directly to discuss your project.  Most would give a quick initial consultation for free to discuss fees and scope of work.
4. That said, here is a list of recent issued patents assigned to Namco Bandai which involve linear motion.  You can use Google Patent search to read these patents. You would want to pay particular attention to the claims of the patents, not the title or the abstract, to determine what invention specifically has been claimed by Namco.

Good luck!

**44 Recent US Patents assigned to Namco related to Linear Motion**

- [US8262477B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US8262477B2) Information storage medium, game device, and method of controlling game device
- [US8210941B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US8210941B2) Medium position detection device, display device, game device and token game device
- [US8142277B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US8142277B2) Program, game system, and movement control method for assisting a user to position a game object
- [US7922584B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7922584B2) Image generation method and information storage medium with program for video game in which operation of the controller beyond a predetermined angle causes a character to attack
- [US7918729B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7918729B2) Program product, image generation system, and image generation method
- [US7881521B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7881521B2) Rotational image generation method, program, and information storage medium and virtual camera
- [US7796132B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US7796132B1) Image generation system and program
- [US7724255B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7724255B2) Program, information storage medium, and image generation system
- [US7722450B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7722450B2) Game system, program, and information storage medium
- [US7710419B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7710419B2)    Program, information storage medium, and image generation system
- [US7566273B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7566273B2)    Game system and image generating method
- [US7367887B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7367887B2)    Game apparatus, storage medium, and computer program that adjust level of game difficulty
- [US7341188B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7341188B2)    Position detection system, game system, and control method for position detection system
- [US7312804B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7312804B2)    Program product, image generation method and image generation system
- [US7281981B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7281981B2)    Image generation method, program, and information storage medium
- [US7129945B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7129945B2)    Image generation method, program and information storage medium
- [US7116334B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7116334B2)    Game system and image creating method
- [US7088366B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7088366B2)    Image generation method, program, and information storage medium
- [US7091972B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7091972B2)    Image generation of shadows utilizing a modifier volume gap region
- [US7046242B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7046242B2)    Game system, program and image generating method
- [US7042463B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7042463B2)    Image generating system and program
- [US7014562B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7014562B2)    Video game machine and after-image display method of video game machine
- [US7015908B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7015908B2)    Image generation system and information storage medium
- [US6927777B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6927777B2)    Image generating system and program
- [US6891534B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6891534B2)    Method, apparatus, storage medium, program, and program product for generating image data of virtual space
- [US6890261B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6890261B2)    Game system, program and image generation method
- [US6850242B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6850242B1)    Image generating system and program
- [US6828969B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6828969B2)    Game system, program and image generating method
- [US6798402B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6798402B1)    Received-light pattern detection apparatus
- [US6795082B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6795082B2)    Image generation system, program and image generation method
- [US6749514B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6749514B1)    Game system and information storage medium
- [US6663491B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6663491B2)    Game apparatus, storage medium and computer program that adjust tempo of sound
- [US6642917B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6642917B1)    Sign perception system, game system, and computer-readable recording medium having game program recorded thereon
- [US6537153B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6537153B2)    Game system, program and image generating method
- [US6448970B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6448970B1)    Image generation apparatus for causing movement of moving body based on flow data for a fluid set on a course, and information storage medium
- [US6388667B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6388667B1)    Image generation device and information storage medium
- [US6320988B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6320988B1)    Skeleton model shape transformation method, image synthesizing apparatus, and information storage medium
- [US6206783B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6206783B1)    Control input device and game system
- [US6139473A](https://www.google.com/patents/US6139473A) Action input device for simulator, and simulator using the same
- [US5997303A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5997303A) Rotary sliding device and a simulator using the same
- [US5704837A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5704837A) Video game steering system causing translation, rotation and curvilinear motion on the object
- [US5723802A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5723802A) Music instrument which generates a rhythm EKG
- [US5707060A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5707060A) Medal dropping game machine
- [US5598516A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5598516A) Image synthesizing system and video game apparatus using the same

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of searches. A novelty search, for example, looks for publications of any kind from any place and time that would show that your great idea is not new and non-obvious. You do that to gauge if your idea might be patentable.

On the other hand, if you are planning to build a product and are concerned about infringing someone else's patent, you would do a freedom to operate search. Only the claims of issued and in-force patents in the countries you plan to sell into are relevant. But, in a freedom to operate search, it isn't only the clever part of your product plans that are at issue. You could invent a car that flys and its tire treads can infringe a Firestone tread pattern utility patent. Of course, switching to non-infringing tires later is easier than redesigning the core of a product.

Although no particular license is required for any searching, people who are serious about freedom to operate searches often want an accompanying opinion that you are clear to make and ship. Only an attorney can provide that since it essentially predicts you having a good outcome if you end up in court. They, rightly, charge a lot for that "insurance policy".